# Achartengine linechart fuzzy

Tags: android, view, colors, charts, achartengine

How to make the achartengine line chart rounded in order to escape the problem you can see at the picture below ?

http://store.picbg.net/pubpic/D0/EC/451fd45d22bcd0ec.png

Comment: Do some search on `aChartEngine`, `stroke`, ...

Comment: Did it with BasicStroke.DOTTED and zero distance between dots.@Der Golem thanks :)